# Unable to run npm install with version specification

Tags: zsh, quoting, wildcards, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a simple npm install with zsh terminal.

```
npm install --save-dev  @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0 
zsh: no matches found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0
```

It appears to be because of the @ in the name of the node module. I cannot find an answer to why this occurs, I have tried altering my path in ~/.zshrc to different values to no avail.

I am able to save any other node module without issue, if there is no @ within the name.

For additional information, it appears to be installing a specific version of a node module as opposed to the name. Running `npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`  would work, but adding the `@^4.0.0` causes the error `zsh: no matches found`.

Comment: Quote the plugin name: `"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“no matches found” means that zsh thinks the word is a wildcard pattern. To tell zsh that you want to use the word literally rather than interpret it as a wildcard pattern, use quotes:

```
npm install --save-dev '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0'
npm install --save-dev "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.0.0"
npm install --save-dev  @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@\^4.0.0
```

Either single quotes or double quotes work here. The difference between the two is that a few characters keep their special meaning within double quotes (`` !"$\` ``) but only `'` itself keeps its special meaning after a `'` (to terminate the single-quoted literal string). Alternatively, put a backslash before each character that has a special meaning to the shell.

Here the problematic character is not `@`, it's `^`. `@` doesn't need to be protected: it can be part of the wildcard construct [`@(…)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators) but only when the `kshglob` option is enabled and it's followed by an opening parenthesis and the parenthesis would need to be quoted anyway and that would be enough to protect the `@`. `^` is not a wildcard character by default, but it is one ([`^foo`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) means “everything that doesn't match `foo`”) when the very popular option [`extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) is enabled. `~` is also a wildcard character under `extended_glob` (`foo~bar` means “everything that matches `foo` except what matches `bar`”). `^` is also a [history expansion character](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion), but only if a word starts with `^` and contains another `^`.

Comment: For the record, `^` is special in quite a few shells including the original Unix shell (these days usually refered to  as the Thompson shell), the Bourne shell, `rc`, and its derivatives and `fish`. See also [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)